# "Edit CV" on every user account (probably moderator only)

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Visiting any user account I see an *Edit CV* link:

> [image: top of a user page, with "Edit CV" link circled]

The link leads to `https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/edit`, letting me edit my *own* CV.

This is almost certainly a moderator-only problem. Either only show me the link on my *own* userpage, or if moderators are supposed to moderate CVs (which I highly doubt), link to the current user CV. But please don't do the latter.

Comment: Quoted because it's important: "But please don't do the latter."

Comment: I would have thought that moderators moderating CV would be a *bad* idea (to say the least).

Comment: @ChrisF: It's so bad we aren't even doing it! :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks for the report, Martijn. This is fixed now.

Yes, this was a moderator only problem. I've removed that link for mods.

Moderators on Stack Overflow are NOT meant to moderate CVs. And even had we put the correct link to that user's CV there, your moderator status on Stack Overflow would not have granted you the ability to see or edit it.

Comment: Thanks Jason, fix confirmed!